# How To Count Max Number Of Consecutive Positive

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to count max number of consecutive positive in Google Sheets and I can't find a solution, I saw this formula on the web but it doesn't work, does anyone have any idea how to do it?

`=MAX(FREQUENCY(IF(A1:M1>0,COLUMN(A1:M1)),IF(A1:M1<0,COLUMN(A1:M1))))`

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with _realistic-looking_ data, and showing your _hand-entered_ expected results there.

Answer (score 1):

To find the length of the longest streak of positive integers in row 4, use this:

`=arrayformula( max( len( split( join( "", left(B4:Y4 > 0) ), "F" ) ) ) )`

Copy the formula down to extend it to additional rows.